# How to open a clickable div with cefsharp and jquery

Tags: jquery, cefsharp

I try to use CEFsharp to navigate over a website and collect some data. I am already able to login and use some buttons to get to several sites of the page.
Now I have a part where I don't get on. The site uses clickable DIVs for the navigation.
This is the sourcecode from the website (as example for better understanding):

```
<div id="ExampleDiv">
   <div data-example="12345">...</div>
   <div data-example="12346">...</div>
   <div data-example="12347">...</div>
</div>
```

In a js-file I found this function:

```
$("#ExampleDiv").on("click", "[data-example]", example),
```

I tried to execute the script with this command (VB):

```
Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$(""#ExampleDiv"").on(""click"", ""[data-example]"", 12345)")
```

[EDIT]
I also tried this, after the hints from amaitland

```
Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('.ExampleDiv div[data-example='12345']').click()")
```

But there I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list@ about:blank:1:2

But this doesn't work.

greetings
BHuelse

Comment: Have you tried $("#ExampleDiv").click();

Comment: No, but I think its not the right way. Because "ExampleDiv" is a parentcontainer and I have to add the Ids from the child (data-example). How is the call without jquery but with parameter?

Comment: My point is call click(); on the relevant div using jQuery.

Comment: Ok, but ExampleDiv is not the right one, because it's the parent. How can I address the correct child?

Comment: You can select a DOM element based on it's data attribute one example is https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value-in-jquery.php there will be plenty of other examples if you search for them.

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for you answer. I tried now this: "$('.ExampleDiv div[data-example='12345']').click()" But this doesn't work. Also tried it with # instead the . before ExampleDiv. When I check the result from CEFSharp I got the error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @ about:blank:1:2" I don't knwo whats wrong in my command.

Comment: Probably the single quotes that's the problem

Comment: Yes the single quotes where the problem :) Now it works! Thanks alot  @amaitland